# The importance of phase when defining fermions and bosons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, bosons

In my lecture on indistinguishable particles, my lecturer is trying to illustrate to me the notion of particles being indistinguishable when considering that when we swap two particles in a box the superposition state looks absolutely the same. She then goes on to note:

> If we consider the *phase* of the wavefunction, then it turns out that there are two possible outcomes for the overall two-particle wavefunction, which either maintains or reverses its sign every time a swap between particles is made

I don't see how this happens. A global phase shouldn't change the wavefunction appreciably. Can someone explain why what she is saying is the case?

Comment: Phase factors can be signed, + or - and therefore act differently. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles

Comment: Ask your lecturer what happens to the phase if you use a density matrix model of the two particles.